# how to add xml schema to coldfusion web service

Tags: web-services, coldfusion, xsd, validation

I am creating a new web service in which the data format should have to made strict using XMLSchema. But I could not find a way to apply detail xml schema in Coldfusion web service

the web service is passing information as XML and they need to be in a strict format which sould be spedicied in the XML Schema , so that No wrong information is passed.

```
<wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <xs:element name="UpdatePendingTicketsRequest">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="SIMS_REPLY_NAVISION_TO_INTOUCH">
        </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="UpdatePendingTicketsResponse">
        <xs:simpleType>             
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="OK"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="ERROR_PROCESSING"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:simpleType name="ST_STATUS">
            <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                <xs:enumeration value="1"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="2"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="99"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
        <xs:element name="TRANSACTIONS">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="TRANSACTION" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="TRANSACTION">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="ORIGINAL_TRANSACTION_ID"/>
                    <xs:element ref="STATUS"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="STATUS">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:simpleContent>
                    <xs:extension base="ST_STATUS">
                        <xs:attribute name="description" use="required">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                    <xs:enumeration value="DUPLICATE"/>
                                    <xs:enumeration value="OK"/>
                                    <xs:enumeration value="PROBLEM"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:attribute>
                    </xs:extension>
                </xs:simpleContent>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="SIMS_REPLY_NAVISION_TO_INTOUCH">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="DATETIME"/>
                    <xs:element ref="TRANSACTIONS"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="ORIGINAL_TRANSACTION_ID" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="DATETIME" type="xs:dateTime"/>
        <xs:element name="FaultStructure">
        <xs:complexType >
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="FaultCode"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="FaultString"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

This is the sample XML Schema which is used to validate the payload. But when i create the same in Coldfusion, this is all i get.

```
<wsdl:types>
  <schema targetNamespace="http://rpc.xml.coldfusion" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <import namespace="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap"/>
   <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
   <complexType name="CFCInvocationException">
    <sequence/>
   </complexType>
  </schema>
 </wsdl:types>
```

I did a lot of search and never found a concrete solution for it.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be answer but I always recommend that do not build webservice in ColdFusion to receive xml document as arguments. Instead use xml string as argument which later you can convert to xml document using xmlParse(). I had such experience in past and later I need to convert it to xml string argument.

Thanks
Pritesh